# How to make fixed navbar transparent based on page scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I want mynavbar to be transparent when the page is scrolled to the top, however when the user scrolls I would like it to be made opaque. I tried this with javascript, but something still isn't working.
http://jsfiddle.net/6A6qy/

```js
function myFunction() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() < 50) {
    document.getElementById("masthead").style.opacity = "0.5";
  }
}
```

```css
#masthead {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #00a087;
  opacity: 1;
}
#container {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 1000px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction()">
  <nav id="masthead">
    <!-- Fixed navigation bar content -->
  </nav>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

JS:

```
// listen for scroll
$(window).scroll( function() {
  // apply css classes based on the situation
  if ($(".masthead").offset().top > 100) {
    $(".masthead").addClass("navbar-scrolled");
  } else {
    $(".masthead").removeClass("navbar-scrolled");
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-scrolled {
  /* some css for navbar when scrolled */
}
```

JSFiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/8ruwnaam/

And then of course you could add some optimization to not apply the classes all the time if they are already there. But it works quite fine without such things as well.

**Additional things:**

The first version of this answer and your question use IDs for styling, which is not really a good idea according to a lot of people. Styling IDs goes against the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principles, and causes all these funny little problems when you forget to think about CSS specificity. IDs are quite alright for a lot of things when it comes to the logic in the JS or something, but try to use classes for styling.

Comment: @EndUser the problem being CSS specificity. ID goes over class. Change the ID `masthead` to a class, and it works fine. Or then change the class thing to changing the actual CSS of that ID. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an `.opaque` css class and attach it based on actively scrolling or if `scrollTop` is < 50:

```
.opaque {
   opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Then attach that class `on('scroll')` or at `scrollTop` (this is using [the debounce plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/)):

```
function myFunction() {
  var $masthead = $('#masthead')
    , $window = $(window);
  // currently scrolling
  $window.scroll($.debounce( 250, true, function(){
    $masthead.addClass('opaque');
  }));
  // done scrolling
  $window.scroll($.debounce( 250, function(){
    // if at the top, add or keep opaque class
    if($(this).scrollTop() < 50) {
      if(!$masthead.hasClass('opaque')) {
         $masthead.addClass('opaque');
      }
    } else {
      $masthead.removeClass('opaque');
    }
  }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it to be transparent by default (as it will be on the top) like that

```
#masthead {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #00a087;
  opacity: 0.5; /*edited the opacity to be 50% by default*/
}
```

then use this script to achieve your needs:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var ScrollTop = parseInt($(window).scrollTop());

        if (ScrollTop < 100) {
            document.getElementById("masthead").style.opacity = "0.5";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("masthead").style.opacity = "1";
        }
    });
});
```